# How to install FIWARE plugin in node-red?

Tags: node-red, fiware

Recently I find out that there is a [FIWARE plugin](https://github.com/FIWARE/node-red-contrib-FIWARE_official) for node red. 
I want to experiment with it. It is an interesting feature. I tried to install it on the latest version of node-red and it is shows only 2 plugins. 
So, what is the correct node red version that is required? 
 Is this requires to install other dependencies as well? 
 Is there any extra steps needed?

*Update*

My logs look ok but the modules doesn't have color label:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in the Node-RED logs (it will list nodes that failed to load at startup)

Comment: Have you restarted Node-RED since installing the nodes?